# How can i save data from a .txt file to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have this file , " File.txt " formatted as a big `array[ ]` , in each index of this array placed in the .txt file there is a *json* i want to use later. I need to read the file , save each *json* and push it in an *array* using *javascript*. Every `{ content }` , `{ content 2}` represents a *json* .

**File.txt**

```
[
 {
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Source","label":"name","group": 0},
    {"id": "Parent_1","label":"name","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_2","label":"name","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_3","label":"name","group": 1},
    {"id": "Child_1","label":"name","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_2","label":"name","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_3","label":"name","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_4","label":"name", "group": 3}
  ],
  "links": [
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_1"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_2"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_3"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_1"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_2"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_3"},
    { "source": "Child_2","target": "Child_4"}
  ]
} ,
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Source","label":"name","group": 0},
    {"id": "Parent_1","label":"name","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_2","label":"name","group": 1},
    {"id": "Parent_3","label":"name","group": 1},
    {"id": "Child_1","label":"name","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_2","label":"name","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_3","label":"name","group": 2},
    {"id": "Child_4","label":"name", "group": 3}
  ],
  "links": [
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_1"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_2"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Parent_3"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_1"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_2"},
    { "source": "Source","target": "Child_3"},
    { "source": "Child_2","target": "Child_4"}
  ]
} 
]
```

I have in mind something like this :

```
//The array i want to save all the data in
NewArray=[];

//Get the file name
 var File = document.getElementById('File.txt');

//Make a loop so i can read each index of the file and save the content in the new array
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    NewArray[i] = "File.[i] ;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript can only read local files. I guess your text file is on the server?

Comment: @hallleron It is local .

Comment: Then edit your file, prefix its contents with `var data = `, and then load it via a `<script src="file.txt"></script>` element.

Comment: @trincot I did exactly as you said , and it works i even tested it with this for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(i + " = " + array[i]);
} sorry i don't know how mark the text as a code in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it work is to edit your text file, and prefix its contents with

```
var data =
```

Then load it via:

```
<script src="file.txt"></script>
```

Once you have that, you can access the data via the `data` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lesen").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt", //get the file from local/server 
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                var arrData = data; //data are in the form of array with json data
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[image: data will be shown like this]

Comment: I put your answer in <script> </script> tags , It should work but it gives me this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  ;

Comment: this means you need to load jquery.

Comment: you need to add jquery script